# Unable To Find the Solution

Tags: laravel-5.8

function login(Request $req)
{

```
            $user= User::where("email",$req->input('email'))->get();
            return Crypt::decrypt($user[0]->password);
            
           }
```

then i put :

function login(Request $req)
{

```
 $user= User::where("email",$req->input('email'))->get();
 return Crypt::decrypt($user[0]->password)==$req->input('password');
            
           }
```

I got the following error:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

Comment: Just a guess, but it's probably because you're using the equals operator which returns a boolean: `Crypt::decrypt($user[0]->password)==$req->input('password')`

Comment: WHAT WILL I USE IN PLACE OF equals operator.?

Comment: I have no idea what your code does so I couldn't tell you...